# Python 2D-plotting of already binned arrays

Tags: python, arrays, histogram, large-data

I have two really large arrays that can't fit in memory at once. I am interested in plotting a 2D histogram of these two arrays with a colorbar. In my case I loop over subsequent chunks of arrays and keep appending first data to `x` and `y`, such that:

```
n_bins=99
histogram = np.zeros(shape=(1,n_bins), dtype=np.float64)  
histogramy = np.zeros(shape=(1,n_bins), dtype=np.float64)
```

and below happens in each (`for`) loop iteration when desired chunk length of x is reached:

```
add_coip, _ = np.histogram(np.asarray(x)[:], bins=(xedges))
add_coipy, _ = np.histogram(np.asarray(y)[:], bins=(yedges))

histogramx += add_coip.astype(np.float64)
histogramy += add_coipy.astype(np.float64)
x,y=[],[] # reset lists to append next chunk
```

Though I get `histogramx` and `histogramy` binned properly, I am unable to plot a 2D histogram using these arrays. Note that `histogramx` and `histogramy` doesn not contain data, rather a binned-version of the data. Any suggestions please?

PS: I understand using `plt.bar` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082402/how-to-build-or-precompute-a-histogram-from-a-file-too-large-for-memory) but that's for a 1D plot!

Comment: Are you using NumPy with Matplotlib to plot?

Comment: @ShannonStarr: I actually tried both `plt.hist2d` and `numpy.histogram2d` and had no luck since the arrays have already-binned data instead of the original data. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Maybe use matplotlib.pyplots.step with documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html (Sorry I am not totally sure)

Comment: @ShannonStarr: Yeah, that actually generates a 1D histogram. My objective here is to generate a 2D histogram. Let me know if you have any other thoughts?

Comment: I think it might be bar3d in matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this, you can use `plt.matshow` as explained [here](https://vmascagn.web.cern.ch/vmascagn/LABO_2020/histograms-advanced.html), it has many of the options available that work for `plt.hist2d`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).